# If $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, must $\tan(f(x))$ be integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove or disprove: if $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $\tan(f(x))$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Im going to disprove this.

My thought process is to think about asymptotes of $\tan(x)$, which are when $\sin x =1,-1$. so it would be undefined at those points.

I admit, Im not 100% with what Im about to say.

Couldn't the points where tan is undefined be considered discontinuities. That is, there are relatively few of them and I could easily find a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,p)< \epsilon$, thus it could be true.

Comment: There is nothing here preventing $f(x)$ from failing to be in the domain of tangent, hence $\tan (f(x))$ may not even be defined on all of $[a,b]$.

Comment: As a side note, $\tan$ is actually a continuous function *on its domain*. It just so happens that it's domain is a disconnected set, hence you cannot draw the entire graph without having to lift your pencil, however, on each connected component of its domain, you can indeed draw that piece of its graph without lifting your pencil.

Comment: Is this Riemann integrable? If so you could call it "almost continuous".

Comment: @JustinBenfield moreover the components have downward bojnded width. Is integrability a topological invariant?

Comment: @Alephnull: Not to my knowledge, but it is closely related to the topology of the space in question because the important structure (most generally a measure for the space in question) can be compatible with the topology in a variety of ways, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics) last paragraph of definition section.

Answer (score 2):

The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & |x|\neq \pi/2\\ 0 & |x|=\pi/2\end{cases}$$ is integrable on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Is $\tan\big(f(x)\big)$ integrable on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, take $f(x) = \arctan(1/x)$ on $[-1,1]$. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arctan(1%2Fx)) is a plot.